# AttributeError: '_socketobject' object attribute 'bind' is read-only

Tags: python

I am beginner in python. I tried to run the code below but I get the error like header in the post. I read similar posts that didn't fix my issue. I tried to run it with python 2.7.13 and the latest 3.6.10. Same issue. The code as follows:

```
import socket
saddress=input("Server Address: ")
sport=input("Server Port: ")
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind=(saddress,sport)
s.listen(1)
print("Server started! Waiting for connections...")
connection,address=s.accept()
print("Client connected with address:", address)

while 1:
    data=connection.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    connection.sendall=('--Message receieved --\n')
    print(data.decode('utf-8'))
connection.close()
```

Comment: `s.bind = (saddress, sport)` is wrong; you're assigning to it, should be `s.bind((saddress, sport))`.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard thank you very much